# Populate textLabel of collectionView with Firebase data

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, collectionview

I have a struct like this:

```swift
struct Item {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var price : Int
}
```

and i have populated this with Firebase observe.
Then i have declared a variable:

```swift
var items: [Item] = []
```

and if i print this var, I can see that every things is working in my console.
But, i want to populate a `CollectionViewCell` `UILabel` with every Item in the array and i wrote this but is still not working:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cella", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let singleItem = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameItem.text = singleItem.name 
    return cell
}
```

I think that the error is in `indexPath.row`.

Comment: what prints when you print `self.items[indexPath.row]`?

Comment: Did you set the delegate properly?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest yes, every things is working.

Comment: @emrcftci nothing. the error is indexPath.row. 
I had already set up reloadData

Comment: @StefanoQuarta what is the error? please share your error, error line and something useful to solve this problem.

Comment: @emrcftci the items array is working and contains this: [Vice.Item(name: "first", description: "olive, carciofi", price: 5), Vice.Item(name: "second", description: "pomodoro, salame, mozzarella", price: 6)]

Comment: If i add self.items[indexPath.row] to SingleItem, this SingleItem receives nothing.
that's why I think the mistake is in indexPath.row

Comment: Add print(indexPath.row) and print(self.items[indexPath.row]) and please ad to your question whats the result

Comment: @MatiasJurfest it doesn't print nothing, cause it is a Structure, not a simply array. I don't know how to pass structures data to the IBOutlet in my collectionCell

Comment: What is Vice in your Vice.Item(name: "first", description: "...", price: 5)?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest the name of parent node into Firebase

Comment: Why the firebase parent node is there? Shouldn't be part of your objects array. Try to fix the parser from firebase, I think your issue is there